# White screen when scrolling the site on apple devices (iphone 11)

Tags: html, css

There is a simple site https://kegelfit.ru When scrolling on the iphone(11) in any browser, there is a kind of delay to the white screen and then the page is shown. I can’t understand what’s the matter. Help me please. Link to video error https://disk.yandex.ru/i/-HUE52SUEGvH2A

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. Please also read: [Can I just link to my website?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Comment: Looks fine on my phone (iPhone 11, iOS 14.8).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The error turned out to be md two lines of css code

Comment: do not post images. answer should be available for search engines